# Flutter : Why This Method Not Works?

Tags: flutter, dart

In QuerySnapshot It Has "Day1" and "Day2" Boths are Day of Week Like "Saturday". If "Day1" or "Day2" is Today I need to Return "true". But This method always returns false. I need to know why the If condition (In Loop) is not working and How can I Solve this?

```
bool class_count(Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream) {
  bool class_ = false;
  String dateFormat = DateFormat('EEEE').format(DateTime.now());
  //This Line Return Day Like "Saturday"
  stream.forEach((element) {
    if (element != null) {
      for (int count = 0; count < element.documents.length; count++) {
        if (element.documents[count].data['Day1'].toString() == dateFormat)
          class_ = true;
        if (element.documents[count].data['Day2'].toString() ==
            dateFormat) if (element.documents[count].data['Day2']
                .toString() ==
            dateFormat) class_ = true;
      }
    }
  });
  print(class_);
  return class_;
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer a little.

Answer (score 3):

Bacause stream's `forEach` is asynchronous. So this loop will not wait while it completes. In your code you set `class_` to `false`, then create a `future` which *will be* executed in future, and return `classs_` at once. So it still equal to `false`.

Try to add `async` suffix to method and `await` before `stream.forEach`. And then your method must return `Future<bool>` and been called as

```dart
final class = await class_count(someStream);
```

I think the best way to handle stream events is add listener for stream and process data in it.

```dart
stream.listener((event) {
  // here must be your code which will be executed each time stream will get event
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`stream.forEach()` method returns a **Future type value**. So you have to call this method inside a another Asynchronous function and also it needs to be await until that future completes.

Solution:-

- Convert your `class_count()` synchronous method to a **Asynchronous method** by,

  1. Adding `async` keyword to method header.
  2. Change your return type into a `Future<bool>`.
- Add `await` keyword before `stream.forEach()` method call (**Asynchronous operation**).

Code:-

*[Read comments carefully to understand the program flow correctly]*

```
//1- Return type should be a Future type => Future<bool>.
//2- Add async keyword before method body => async.
Future<bool> class_count(Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream) async{
  bool class_ = false;
  String dateFormat = DateFormat('EEEE').format(DateTime.now());

  //3 - Adding await keyword before asynchronous operation => await.
  //
  await stream.forEach((element) {
    if (element != null) {
      for (int count = 0; count < element.documents.length; count++) {
        if (element.documents[count].data['Day1'].toString() == dateFormat)
          class_ = true;
        if (element.documents[count].data['Day2'].toString() ==
            dateFormat) if (element.documents[count].data['Day2']
                .toString() ==
            dateFormat) class_ = true;
      }
    }
  });
  //After stream.forEach() method completes its loop these below statements will execute.
  //Every statements inside the function body will only execute one after another.
  //so below statements are only executes after the above operation completes.
  print(class_);
  return class_;
}
```

*One extra tip :- By using StreamSubcription you can get streams of data, instead of future.*